# Sample code for adding Splash screen in xcode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad, splash-screen

Can anyone provide me a sample code for adding a splash screen to an existing Xcode project.  What is the better way to add a splash screen?  I mean is it using model view controller or just adding the image in resource folder.  And if I want to play any movie on the splash screen then how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Splash screen of video type right?

Go through these source code steps.

http://iphonedevcentral.blogspot.com/2010/08/display-iphone-movies-in-portrait-mode.html

Write your own Utility Class. And on Video Done clicked show your home screen

Code: http://iosdevelopertips.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/MoviePlayer-Portrait-Mode-ios4.zip

Comment: but here the video is played only after we click some button,i want that when my app loads then inspite of the default image ,i want to play a default movie clip and that too without clicking any button

Comment: You have to create one intermediate class of UIViewCOntroller type and add it in your window in appDelegate class. So as soon as you will launch your app Video will looks like a splash screen. And in video end delegates just call your homeController class whichever is your application first screen. Just do some coding stuffs with your project

Comment: there is no sample available like that.... its just simple way that...take an object of MPMoviePlayerController .. play it in your window as soon as your application launched and in movieFinishedCallback delegate redirect your controller to your mainController thats it

Comment: do i ahev to take the object in app ddi finish launching method also lets say rootview contoller is my main view then do i have to setr root view controller as main view ,,show me the line how to write this

Comment: Suppose you have AppDelegate and HomeViewController... you have to create one more PLayViewController which you have to add it in appdelegate window.. and then you have to write declare in loadView that MPMoviePlayerController *player and make notification for movieFinishedCallback.. and in that delegate launch your HomeViewController

Comment: can u mail to one of my cousins id please

Comment: my ids are blocked here cant do anything from herer

Comment: UIScroll view problem ,help yar